# ViewPager Controller in Xamarin for IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, pivot, viewpage

Is there any ViewPager controller for ios in Xamarin C# Language. 
Which look simpler to pivot controller in windows phone.

I search a lot i found [ICViewPager](https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager)  but its in X-Code Objective-C language

Is there any controller that helps to create ViewPager.

@All
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UIScrollView that enables paging ( there is a property enabling this on the UIScrollView ) in combination with UIPageControl. I'm sure you can find some tutorials online about this subject. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/45818/UIScrollView-with-paging-sample-for-Monotouch-Deve) is one.